# Gridlayout cardview Select Item in Fragment and change background android studio

Tags: android, cardview, background

buenas tardes gente que tal
bueno estoy haciendo una utilizando android studio y tengo una app que tiene un tablayout y dentro de ese tablayout lleva un gridlayout junto con cardview.
[image: app]

el problema que quiero añadir  que el card view cambie el color de fondo  al hacer clik

[image: gridview]

como se ve en esta imagen  este ejemplo esta en un activitymain a parte
pero al llevar este código a la app principal no funciona nada

```
    GridLayout mainGrid;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mainGrid = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainGrid);
    
    setSingleEvent(mainGrid);
}

private void setSingleEvent(GridLayout mainGrid) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mainGrid.getChildCount(); i++) {
        //You can see , all child item is CardView , so we just cast object to CardView
        final CardView cardView = (CardView) mainGrid.getChildAt(i);
        cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (cardView.getCardBackgroundColor().getDefaultColor() == -1) {
                    //Change background color
                    cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6F00"));
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "State : True", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    //Change background color
                    cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "State : False", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

no se que estoy haciendo mal o donde debo añadir este codigo  ya que lo añado al pizzas.java. aquí adjunto mi  fragmento  y mis actividades.java

**pizzas.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

   public class pizzas extends Fragment {

     private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
     private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
     private String mParam1;
     private String mParam2;

     public pizzas() {
     }

public static pizzas newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    pizzas fragment = new pizzas();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pizzas, container, false);
 }
}
```

mi diseño XML  fragment_pizza.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".pizzas"
android:baselineAligned="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#F2B138"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="990dp"
            android:layout_weight="12"
            android:padding="14dp"
            app:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            app:columnCount="2"
            app:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            app:rowCount="3">


            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/me_time" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Me"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

mi  adaptador de viewpager para deslizar  fragmentos en el tablayout AdapterPage.java

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager; 
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout;

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private int tabsNumber;
public PagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, int behavior, int tabs) {
    super(fm, behavior);
    this.tabsNumber = tabs;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            return new pizzas();
        case 1:
            return new refresco();
        case 2:
            return new burgers();
        case 3:
            return new combos();
        default: return  null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tabsNumber;
}  
}
```

mi activity main.java  donde presento el tablayout

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
NavigationView navigationView;
ViewPager pager;
TabLayout mTabLayout;
TabItem pizzas,refresco,burger,combo;
PagerAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    pager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mTabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tablayout);

    pizzas = findViewById(R.id.pizzas);
    refresco = findViewById(R.id.refresco);
    burger = findViewById(R.id.burger);
    combo = findViewById(R.id.combo);

    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.open,R.string.close);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    toggle.syncState();

    adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), 
    FragmentPagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT,mTabLayout.getTabCount());
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    mTabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(mTabLayout));
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.incioitem){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Inicio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.mtpago){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Metodo de Pago", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.helponline){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Ayuda en Linea", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.tyc){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Terminos y Condiciones", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return false;
}
 }
```

hay un lugar especifico donde tenga que añadir el codigo o se debe llamar de otra manera

Comment: No pongas el título en inglés. Por otra parte, ¿Tu problema es que en tu App1 te funciona pero en tu App2 no?

Comment: soy nuevo en esta plataforma jeje,  exacto  la app de pruebas donde tengo el codigo funcionando se muestra bien pero al querer implementarlo a la otra la principal donde esta el tablayout  no funciona, tengo entendido que el fragmento es muy diferente a un activity. entonces no se como llamar estos en un fragmento o en que lugar del fragmento lo puedo añadir